# Declaring a custom data Type containing a late-bound Dictionary Object

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, types, late-binding

Can a Custom Type be declared having as one of its elements a Dictionary Object that is late-bound? e.g. in a Standard Module or a Class Module:

```
Private Type InternalData
    sName as String
    cSheets as Collection    'cSheets as New Collection
    wBook as Workbook
    bFiles as CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")    'bFiles as New CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Type
```

OR Is there an alternative way? Please note, i don't want to early bind the Dictionary.

Comment: You can't use `CreateObject` as a declaration anywhere. You'll have to just declare it as Object. Or use a class and then you can use `CreateObject` in the `Initialize` event

Comment: @Rory thanks for your comment. Is it possible for you to share a working example in a class having a custom Type declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will handle your dictionary object similar to how you handle your workbook object.  Declare your dictionary as type `Object` and then initialize it someplace else.  For example, in a Form you could have:

```
Private Type InternalData
    sName As String
    cSheets As Collection
    wBook As Workbook
    bFiles As Object
End Type

Public Sub TryIt()
   Dim id As InternalData
   Set id.bFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   id.bFiles.Add Key, Value
End Sub
```

Based on comments, here's how you could do it with a class.  In a Class Module:

```
Public sName As String
Public cSheets As Collection
Public wBook As WorkBook
Public bFiles As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set bFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
```

and then like before, perhaps in a Form:

```
Public Sub TryIt()
   Dim id As InternalData
   id.bFiles.Add Key, Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Brian, I understand now what@Rory meant by initializing it in a class_initialize() event.

Comment: @Brian In VBA the use of custom Types is a bit of a dead end.  You will be much much better off if you change change your type to an Class, even if you just set the class to contain public fields.  You then also have the advantage that when you create a new object you can initialize the dictionary as part of the object initialisation.